# Online data giving numbers and frequencies of nouns in some well-known novels?

Tags: reference-request, corpora, datasets

Are there any freely available online data giving the numbers and frequencies of nouns used in some well-known novels, whether or not the novels are in the public domain? I mean data such as

> Dan Brown, *The Da Vinci Code*
>   No. of noun instances: 30407
>   No. of unique nouns: 900
>   Nouns appearing once: 17
>   Nouns appearing twice: 32
>   etc.

(Note: these are made up data!)

Comment: Alternatively, you could generate this yourself. For example, NLTK has a tutorial for the 25000 works of Project Gutenberg: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html

Comment: Thanks for this link, but it would seem to be a huge programming job to determine what was and wasn't a noun, e.g. with a string such as "The first set itself", the program would have to work out whether that was a sentence or a sentence fragment.

Comment: Not a very large job (there are tagged corpora, and standard taggers), but I understand it's not the ready-made data you asked for.